# Drawing a line with coordinates given in pixels in OpenGL

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl

I am trying to create a 400x300 screen with a line traveling from point (180,15) to point (10,145). Here is my display function where I create the line:

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
  GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context
  gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear color and depth buffers
  gl.glLoadIdentity();  // reset the model-view matrix


  gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //set color of line
  gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f); // translate into the screen
  gl.glBegin(GL_LINES); 
    gl.glVertex2f(180, 15); //specify line-segment geometry must use relative values
    gl.glVertex2f(10,145);
  gl.glEnd();

  gl.glFlush();
}
```

This is the init function where I first define the orthographic parameters of the screen:

```
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = (GL2) drawable.getGL();    // get the OpenGL graphics context
    drawable.setGL(new DebugGL2(gl));   //set debugger. This will come in handy.
    glu = new GLU();                         // get GL Utilities
    gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);      // set clear depth value to farthest
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enables depth testing
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // sets base color for glClear()
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // the type of depth test to do
    gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // best perspective correction
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting

    //orthographic parameters set here
    glu.gluOrtho2D(0, 200, 0, 150);

}
```

and this is the reshape function that (from what I understand) is called whenever the viewing screen is resized.

```
@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context

    if (height == 0) height = 1;   // prevent divide by zero
    float aspect = (float)width / height;
    glu = new GLU();

    // Set the view port (display area) to cover the entire window
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
    glu.gluOrtho2D(0, 200, 0, 150); //set 2-D orthographic context

    glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0); // fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar


    // Enable the model-view transform
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset

}
```

I have also tried using:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glOrtho(0,200,150,0,-1,1);
```

and

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);
```

ie using a relative scale. However, nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: you do understand what perspective projection is, do you?

Comment: Multiplying one projection matrix by another is rather meaningless. Comment out either your `gluOrtho2D` or `gluPerspective` call.

Comment: Andon, when I comment out the gluPerspective call nothing is rendered on the screen. Pavel, I understand that I am projecting an image on a screen based on a world coordinate system which I defined using either gluOrtho2D or glOrtho.

Comment: I corrected the title. I had written pixel instead of point. I am trying to figure out how to correctly create a line from 2 points on a canvas. Currently, I cannot make sense of the behavior of the line on my canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the area, or *viewport*, within the window to draw to

   ```
   gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); //in pixels
   ```
2. Set up the projection so your OpenGL coordinates are in pixels (match the width/height of the viewport)

   ```
   //we want to modify the projection matrix (without this, mesh normals will break)
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

   //clear any previous transforms the projection matrix may contain (otherwise it would be combined with the following glOrtho matrix)
   gl.glLoadIdentity();

   //set the projection (could use glTranslate/glScale but this utility function is simpler)
   gl.glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1); //left,right,bottom,top,front,back

   //common practice to leave modelview as the current matrix for editing
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   ```

   Now the viewing volume is the box defined by `glOrtho`.

   Note that `(0, 0)` is currently bottom left. If you're doing any GUI stuff it's quite useful to flip this and make the origin top left as we read left to right and down. There's nothing stopping you from changing half way through drawing - do some 3D stuff with some arbitrary coordinate system, then draw a HUD and set up the projection to match pixels.
3. In your display function draw your line...

   ```
   gl.glBegin(GL_LINES); 
   gl.glVertex2f(180, 15);
   gl.glVertex2f(10,145);
   gl.glEnd();
   ```

   or, to demonstrate the use of a translate

   ```
   gl.glLoadIdentity(); //remove the following translate that's still in the modelview matrix from the previous display() call
   gl.glTranslatef(180, 15); //modifies the modelview matrix
   gl.glBegin(GL_LINES); 
   gl.glVertex2f(0, 0);
   gl.glVertex2f(-170, 130);
   gl.glEnd();
   ```

   you could think of the translate moving the *view* down and to the left, or moving the *model* (the line) up and to the right

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This seems to have worked.